# MVC4 application can not see any membership section

Tags: asp.net-membership, asp.net-mvc-4, sqlmembershipprovider

Just installed VS 2012(Ultimate) and created a MVC4 application.

When I looked into web.config, I can not find any membership, role or profile providers sections.

Curious to know where they are set.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Actually it takes the value from machine.config. And the default provider is 'AspNetSqlMembershipProvider'

Thanks

Comment: anybody known anyway to override ?